# How to sendbroadcast in callback function

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, native, broadcast

I create an android project, project is a service, no UI. Java layer(function name is onReceive) will receive a broadcast to startservice. And a native c function(function name is startService) will be called. The C function will create a thread, in this thread, it will call function(function name are SendLaResult(native) and SendLaResult(java)) in Java. And the java function will sendBroadcast to another APP. This is a major flow.
The following code is sample.

#### 1. start work

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
...
          new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String str="test";
                    startService(str);
                    Log.i(TAG, "startService end!!!");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
...
}
```

#### 2. native-lib.cpp, call funtion in java.

```
void SendResult( LaResult         laResult)
{
    bool isAttached = false;
    if(!isAttached) {
        int getEnvStat = g_JavaVM->GetEnv((void **)&g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        if(getEnvStat < 0) {
            jint status = g_JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&g_env, NULL);
            if(status >= 0) {
                isAttached = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(g_env == NULL) {
        LOGE("g_env is NULL!!!");
    }

    jshort conf = laResult.conf ;
    jshort nls = laResult.nls ;
    jshort egoln = laResult.egoln ;

    g_laresult_constructor = g_env->GetMethodID(g_callback_laresult,"<init>","(SSSI[S)V");
    if(g_laresult_constructor == NULL) {
        LOGE("GetMethodID laresult error!!!");
    }

    jobject jparams = g_env->NewObject(g_callback_laresult, g_laresult_constructor, conf, nls, egoln);
    if(jparams == NULL) {
        char * str=strerror(errno);
        LOGE("NewObject jparams error %s !!!" ,str);
    }

    g_mid_sendlaresult = g_env->GetMethodID(g_callback_laservice, "SendLaResult", "(Lcom/xxx/xxx/xxxx/LaResult;)V");
    if(g_mid_sendlaresult == NULL) {
        LOGE("GetMethodID g_mid_sendlaresult error!!!");
    }

    jobject serviceobject = g_env->AllocObject(g_callback_laservice);
    if(serviceobject == NULL) {
        LOGE("AllocObject serviceobject error!!!");
    }

    g_env->CallVoidMethod(serviceobject, g_mid_sendlaresult, jparams);

    g_env->DeleteLocalRef(jparams);
    if(isAttached ) {
        g_JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    }

    return;
}
```

#### 3.LaService.java, sendBroadcast to another APK

```
public void SendLaResult(LaResult laresult) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction( "com.xxx.xxx.xxx.LA_RESULT" );
    intent.putExtra( "conf", laresult.conf);
    Log.d( "confidence", Integer.toString(laneresult.confidence) );
    intent.putExtra( "nls", laresult.nls);
    Log.d( "nLanes", Integer.toString(laneresult.nLanes) );
    intent.putExtra( "egoln", laresult.egoln);

    sendBroadcast( intent );
}
```

#### 4. When the sendBroadcast is called, the following crash occur.

```
--------- beginning of crash
01-02 18:05:11.505 13501-13537/com.xxx.xxx.xxxxx
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
Process: com.xxx.xxx.xxxx, PID: 13501
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:431)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.SendLaResult(LaService.java:94)
```

I found that the sendBroadcast is asynchronous, it is called by system finally, and return immediately. So i delete the following source code in function SendResult.

```
g_JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
```

That crash don't occur, however, the following error log occur, please refer to source code in function SendResult.

```
01-02 18:15:03.696 13707-13743/com.xxx.xxx.xxxx
E/native-lib: NewObject jparams error Success !!!
```

How to fix the first issue(sendBroadcast crash)
Or how to fix the send issue(NewObject return null)
Please give some suggestion.

Comment: Until your newly created service has been attached it will not have a base context, and therefore `ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast` will fail with a `NullPointerException`. I don't really see the point in this native code though. Why can't you just do all of this in Java?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your reply, i agree with you. However, i have to implmente all job in native side, i can't do all of this in Java. Overall, there is a loop in native thread, for every loop, after a result is created, we need sendBroadcast the result to other APP.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue.
Do not sendbroadcast in function SendLaResult, store every LaResult to a list, create another thread in Oncreate, in this thread sendboadcast every item in list.